# How do you make the entire DIV clickable to go to another page?

Tags: javascript, css, templates, html

**Do not bind it to javascript "onclick".**

It needs to be an anchor.

I know I can bind onclick to the div and make it window.location. However, then...the user cannot open a new tab by CONTROL+Clicking it.

I just want an `<a>` that fills up the entire div.

Comment: Please elaborate. A DIV can have onclick, so you're doing something else wrong. Post some code.

Comment: Did HTML5 "href anywhere" go anywhere?

Comment: Why don't you use anchor tag only. You can style it to not to have link effect

Comment: A lot of people have commented on ways to make anchors look like DIVs. If that's good enough from you, I think `display: block` is the most important property to keep in mind, as anchors are normally inline elements.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try setting the anchor to display as a block within your DIV and setting its height to 100%, like this:

```
<style>
  a { display: block; height: 100% }
  #test { width: 100px; height: 200px; background: red;  }
</style>


<div id='test'><a href='#'>...</a></div>
```

You can see a working example here: http://jsbin.com/ujoca3/2/edit

Comment: @Fred `display: block;` ensures that the child occupies the available width of it's parent by default.

Comment: a block element, by default, expands to fill its parent. You only need to set a width explicitly if its a) less then 100%, or b) a floated element. In this scenario, setting the width is completely unnecessary.

Answer (score 2):

The semantic way to do it would be to have the anchor act like a div. Because you don't want anything else in the container there's no point in having a container.

```
<style>
    a.fakeDiv, a.fakeDiv:link, a.fakeDiv:hover, a.fakeDiv:active, a.fakeDiv:visited{
       display: block;
       text-decoration: none;
       color: Black;
       cursor: default;
       outline: none;
    }
</style>
<a class="fakeDiv">Content</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div>
  <a href="somepage.php" style="display: block; height:100%; width: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0;"></a>
</div>
```

Comment: This doesn't work because anchors are inline elements by default, and you can't actually give them a height in this manner.

Comment: Thanks for the comment! I should have realised this :)

Answer (score 0):

some html:

```
<div><a href="#"></a></div>
```

some css

```
yourdiv { position: relative; }
yourdiv a { position:absolute; left:0;right:0;top:0;bottom:0; }
```

Comment: Maybe make it `position: relative !important;`