# In Rails 3, how can you make a div a button (a clickable div that links to a new page)

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, html, hyperlink

I know that there are options to do this manually, such as here : [How do you make the entire DIV clickable to go to another page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4333195/how-do-you-make-the-entire-div-clickable-to-go-to-another-page)

However, in Rails 3 we make links like this: 
     <%= link_to "name", url %>

And I am wondering -- is there a proper Rails way to make a whole div a button. I realize I could make a button. However, let's say I want to fill it with content like text and a picture - then how would I make that whole div clickable in a rails way?

For example: 
     
         <%= @story.title %>
         <%= @story.blurb %>

In this example, I would want to make #story clickable, with the rails generated content that I specified.. Any ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For those interested, the answer is:

```
 <div class="class_name">
 <%= link_to content_tag(:span, "Text for the LInk"), route %>
 </div>
```

And then, in the CSS set .class_name to position:relative; and:

```
 .class_name span {
width:100%;
height:100%;
position:absolute;
z-index:2;
top:0px;
left:0px;
 }
```

The link will now assume the size of its parent container, and thus give the impression the whole container is a link.

Answer (score 0):

I think that button_to is what you need :

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-button_to

Answer (score 0):

I might use jquery if you *really* wanted to do this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#somediv').click(function(event){
        document.location = 'http://someplace.com';
    });
});
```

You can't make a "clickable" raw div like that in a rails way... the concept doesn't make any sense.  That's just not how it works

(added missing close parens for click)

**not tested**